# Can I get a Span<byte> that references a struct member field of non-byte type?

Tags: c#

Say I have a struct like the following:

```
struct MyStruct {
  Guid g;
}
```

Is it possible to get a `Span<byte>` that references the bytes of the struct?

```
struct MyStruct {
  Guid g;

  public void Foo() {
    Span<byte> bytes = ???
  }
}
```

Such that `bytes` would be a `Span<byte>` of length 16 that would allow reading and writing the individual bytes of the Guid field directly.

I can do something similar with unsafe code, but it seems that this should now be possible with safe code via span, but I can't figure out how to produce the span.

Edit: Clarify that I want a Span that points to the actual storage location of the Guid. Meaning `new Span<byte>(g.ToByteArray))` is not what I'm looking for. That will allocate a new array, copy the bytes to the array, and create a Span referencing the newly allocated array. Modifying bytes via such a span will not modify the Guid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in .Net Core 2.1 or above:

```
            Span<MyStruct> valSpan = MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan(ref mystruct, 1);
            Span<byte> span = MemoryMarshal.AsBytes(valSpan);
```

But use with caution, you should not contain any pointer or reference type in your struct, since GC can move reference type. Actually, it will do runtime check and throw an exception if you do that.

Comment: I knew there must be a straightforward way to do this. Thanks!

Comment: @joe Would this still work if the struct is allocated _inside_ of managed object on the GC heap (as opposed to being allocated on the stack)? I mean what happens if the struct's memory location changes due to GC - how would this affect span created with MemoryMarshal? And is there a difference to taking a ref of a _field inside_ of a struct?

Answer (score 4):

You can force the `Guid` to an array

```
struct MyStruct {
   public Guid g;
}

...

var s = new MyStruct();
var span = new Span<byte>(s.g.ToByteArray());
span[2] = 4;
```

**Note** : The above will not modify the original struct. However, as you pointed out, you can do this with `unsafe`

```
var s = new MyStruct();
var span = new Span<byte>(&s , Marshal.SizeOf(s));

// woah it just become mutable 
span[2] = 4;
```

Comment: So it would seem this is only possible with unsafe code then? Maybe that makes sense, since this would allow violating all kinds of constraints. Imagine the Guid field was marked readonly: it would violate that with *safe* code.

Comment: @MarkPflug exactly, you could get into all sorts of trouble, `unsafe` or `Marshal.StructureToPtr` is really the only way to get a pointer to structure and be able to modify it

Answer (score 0):

Look at the constructors of `Span` class, the only ways to create a `Span` is providing a managed array or a pointer.

But `Guid` is made up with 1 int, 2 shorts and 8 bytes, not a byte array.

So it's impossible (at least not now).